# In perl, checking an array for a value and removing it if exists for each value of another array

Tags: arrays, perl

Basically, I have an array, let's say `@badvalues`.

I have another array, let's say `@values`.

Basically, I want this:

For each element in `@badvalues`

- See if it is in `@values`
- If it is, delete it
- Ultimately, I should end up with either the array `@values`, containing no elements that are in the array `@badvalues`, or a new array, `@goodvalues`, containing every element of `@values` that is not an element of `@badvalues`.

I know it sounds simple, and maybe it's because I'm tired, but I can't seem to find a clear answer to this question when searching around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find elements that are in one array but not another in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/how-can-i-find-elements-that-are-in-one-array-but-not-another-in-perl)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# Get only bad values
my %values = map {$_=>1} @values;
my @new_badvalues = grep { !$values{$_} } @badvalues;

# Get only good values
my %badvalues = map {$_=>1} @badvalues;
my @goodvalues = grep { !$badvalues{$_} } @values;

# An alternative
@badvalues{@badvalues} = ();
foreach $item (@values) {
    push(@goodvalues, $item) unless exists $badvalues{$item};
}
```

For more complete reference, please see "Chapter 4.7. Finding Elements in One Array but Not Another" of "Perl Cookbook"

Comment: Thank you! Virtual brownie for you.

Comment: Stackoverflow: making simultaneous references to weed and Perl since 2010!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a modern Perl version, like say >= 5.10.1, then you can also do this:

`my @final_good = grep { !($_ ~~ @badvalues ) } @values;`

or for clearer precendence:

`my @final_good = grep { not $_ ~~ @badvalues } @values;`

This is using the smartmatch operator that was added in Perl 5.10.

Comment: I wish the Perl I got to work with was that modern, I'm on 5.6.1 :(
Thanks for the tip tho, I'll remember that.

Comment: @Interwebs - I'd feel bad for you, but some of our stuff is still stuck on 5.005. Shame on us!

Answer (score 1):

Little bit faster and less memory consuming version of approach shown in [DVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452692/in-perl-checking-an-array-for-a-value-and-removing-it-if-exists-for-each-value-o/3452748#3452748)

```
my %badvalues;
@badvalues{@badvalues} = ();
my @goodvalues = grep !exists $badvalues{$_}, @values;
```

Comment: I doubt there exists code in the world, except a few pathological cases, where doing the above optimization would be noticeably beneficial. However, it degrades readability.

Comment: this code is taking the hash generator from my second example followed by hash usage from my first example :). Still a valid code, of course - this comment is meant as an excuse of why I didn't include this solution as well; and not a criticism of yours :)

Comment: @szbalint: You can be surprised but there is practical reasons to write code like this. It is lot of easier write this sort of perl code to get 38% more performance and same 38% less memory footprint instead write much less readable C code in XS module. This almost two fifth of speed can be difference between usable and unusable in real project. And if you compare `my %badvalues = map {$_=>1} @badvalues;` and `my %badvalues; @badvalues{@badvalues} = ();` there is not so much difference in readability.

Comment: @szbalint: depends on the reader.  If you are familiar with the idiom, it's easier to read the empty-assignment-to-hash-slice than the map.