# Comparing two arrays, removing items that match

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays, `@names` and `@employees`, that are filled with strings that represent names.  `@names` is 2 dimentional, holding references to anonymous arrays, but the location of the data we care about is at `@names[i][0]`.  I want to loop through `@names` and find which names are not in `@employees`.

At first I thought that looping through `@names` backwards, comparing it to `@employees` and deleting any matches from `@names` would work, but I run into some errors.  Here's what I have:

```
for my $i (reverse(0 .. $#names)) {
  foreach my $employee (@employees) {
    if ($names[$i][0] eq $employee) {  # line 67
      splice(@names, $i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I run into this error:

> Use of uninitialized value in string eq at script.pl line 67,  line 2.

The strings are all defined in the array.  So I'm guessing that this is caused from me deleting elements in the array while I am looping through it, but I thought that looping through the array backwards would prevent an issue like this from happening.

So where am I going wrong in my loop?  Also, I've been really struggling with this loop and that hints to me that something is wrong with my entire thought process.  Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find elements that are in one array but not another in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/how-can-i-find-elements-that-are-in-one-array-but-not-another-in-perl)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no reason to explicitly loop here.  You want to filter names: that's a `grep`.  You want to check membership: that could be done by a `grep` too.

```
@names = grep {my $name = $$_[0]; not grep $_ eq $name, @employees} @names;
```

The repeated scanning of the inner array isn't particularly efficient; it can be avoid by pre-populating a set (really a hash) ahead of time.

```
my %employees = map +($_ => 1), @employees;
@names = grep !$employees{$$_[0]}, @names;
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to just use the value directly? @names = grep !$employees{$_}, @names;

Comment: @DanLittlejohn According to OP, `@names` is a two-dimensional array, so `$_` will still be a list reference.  Stringifying it (which is what happens to hash keys) isn't useful.

Comment: This gives a `Can't use string as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use`

Answer (score 0):

Without providing code, what I would do is return a new list of @names.  For each name in @names, check if it is in @employees, if not add it to your new list of names.