# Perl - deleting items of one array from another array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays called `@these_conf_users` `@these_account_users` which look as follows:

```
adrian bruce malcolm

brom testwp sajay bruce ast domainte adrian rahul freddy onetwo
```

The aim is to remove the elements from the second array if they exist in the first array. [Using this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/how-can-i-delete-items-from-an-array-in-another-array-in-perl), this is what I did:

```
my %sorter;
@sorter{ @these_conf_users } = ();
@tester = grep ! exists $sorter{$_}, @these_account_users;
print "@these_conf_users";
print "@these_account_users";
print "@tester";
```

But this doesn't exclude the duplicate elements. Here's the output:

```
adrian bruce malcolm
brom testwp sajay bruce ast domainte adrian rahul freddy onetwo
brom testwp sajay bruce ast domainte adrian rahul freddy onetwo
```

What I missing here?

Comment: So why the `PHP` tag?

Comment: works fine http://codepad.org/DDsqNhIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @these_account_users = qw/ adrian bruce malcolm /;
my @these_conf_users = qw/ brom testwp sajay bruce ast domainte adrian rahul freddy onetwo /;

my %sorter;
@sorter{ @these_conf_users } = ();
my @tester = grep ! exists $sorter{$_}, @these_account_users;

print "@these_conf_users\n";
print "@these_account_users\n";
print "@tester\n";
```

**output**

```
brom testwp sajay bruce ast domainte adrian rahul freddy onetwo
adrian bruce malcolm
malcolm
```