# Finding any elements of array B that are not in array A

Tags: arrays, perl

Be forewarned, I'm a bit of a Perl novice.

I'm looking for a nice shorthand to compare two arrays, say `arrA` and `arrB`.

I want to know if there are any elements in `arrB` that are not inside `arrA`.

If it matters, the elements inside these arrays are strings.

I'm aware that I can accomplish this by iterating through the arrays and using `grep`, but I'd like to know if there's a nice shorthand way to do this. My Perl-fu is lacking.

Thanks!

**edit:** Here's what I'm looking for, in case I was unclear above.

```
my @arrA = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" );
my @arrB = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" );
my @BnotA = ();

# Something goes here, help!

print "Elements of arrB that are not in arrA: @BnotA\n";
```

I'm not picky about the data structures here though; if I can change the structure a bit to make it more efficient, I can do that.

Comment: Your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2933347/725418 This is also in perlfaq.

Comment: [`perlfaq4 - How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I wasn't sure what to call this to even search for it... "difference" and "intersection" were the keys here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find elements that are in one array but not another in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/how-can-i-find-elements-that-are-in-one-array-but-not-another-in-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is to build a hash from the contents of `@arrA`. Then the elements of `@arrB` can be quickly checked to see if they exist in `@arrA`.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arrA = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" );
my @arrB = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" );

my %arrA_hash = map { $_ => 1 } @arrA;
my @BnotA = grep { not $arrA_hash{$_} } @arrB;

print "Elements of arrB that are not in arrA: @BnotA\n";
```

**output**

```
Elements of arrB that are not in arrA: ddd
```

Alternatively, if you have the [`Array::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/module/Array%3a%3aUtils) module or are willing to install it, you can use that module's `array_minus` function. That would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Array::Utils 'array_minus';

my @arrA = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" );
my @arrB = ( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" );

my @BnotA = array_minus(@arrB, @arrA);

print "Elements of arrB that are not in arrA: @BnotA\n";
```

The output is identical to that of the previous program.