# What is the best way to exclude elements from an array by indexes in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I use the following code to exclude elements in `@{$x}` at indexes in `@{$index}`. But I am not sure it is the most efficient way to implement this function. Does anybody have any better way to do.

```
sub arrayexclude {
    my $x = shift;
    my $index = shift;

    my @keep_index = (0 .. (scalar(@{$x})-1));

    delete @keep_index[@{$index}];

    my $result=[];

    for my $i (@keep_index) {
        if(defined $i) {
            push @{$result}, @{$x}[$i];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: As a more of a side note, `0 .. (scalar(@{$x})-1)` is much more easily written `0 .. $#$x`, or if you prefer `0 .. $#{$x}`.

Comment: `$#foo` is often misused, and if you're adding 1 to it, you're doing something wrong... but if you're ranging over the indices of an array, or talking about the last index, it's exactly the thing you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything beyond an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), so I'd avoid creating a sub just for this.

```
my @wanted = @array[@indices];
```

If you're working with array references, the same recipe applies:

```
my @wanted = @{$array}[@$indices];
```

Comment: I believe OP needs to _exclude_ elements at those indices.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a hash so to identify indices efficiently, then index into the original array with it.

```
my %ref_index;
@ref_index{ @ind_toss } = ();    
@arr_filt = @arr_orig[ grep { !exists $ref_index{$_} } (0..$#arr_orig) ];
```

Final `@arr_filt` contains elements of the `@arr_orig` at indices other than those in `@ind_toss`.

See solution by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/how-can-i-find-elements-that-are-in-one-array-but-not-another-in-perl) for filtering array elements by another array in general.

---

Wrap it in a sub and run. Array with indices to exclude is `@ind_toss`, original array is `@arr_orig`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ind_toss = (1, 4, 5);
my @arr_orig = ('a', '1', 'b', 'c', '2', '6', 'd', 'e');

my @filtered = @{ filter_array_by_index(\@arr_orig, \@ind_toss) };

print "@filtered" . "\n";    

sub filter_array_by_index {
    my ($rarr, $rind) = @_;    
    my %ref_index;
    @ref_index{ @$rind } = (); 
    return [ @$rarr[grep { !exists $ref_index{$_} } (0..$#$rarr)] ];
}
```

Prints

```
a b c d e
```

---

**Notes**

The `return` from the sub, as hinted in comment by [Oleg V. Volkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936986/oleg-v-volkov), can also be written as

```
return [ map { !exists $ref_index{$_} ? $rarr->[$_] : ()  } (0..$#$rarr) ];
```

This avoids construction of a list by `grep` and a slice but rather indexes into the array conditionally.

Comment: Actually, this prints `6`

Comment: @ChatterOne  Fixed, thank you very much.  A typo from a different version :(

Comment: Why `grep` + slice if you can `map` right away and get rid of temporary indices array?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean up a bit on zdim's answer (which is correct anyway):

```
sub filter_array_by_index {
    my ( $rarr, $rind ) = @_;
    my %ref_index = map { $_ => 1 } @ind_toss;
    my @indices = grep { !$ref_index{$_} } (0..$#$rarr);

    return @{$rarr}[@indices];
}
```